# How to deploy an Ember CLI app to Azure Websites

Tags: azure, ember.js, web-deployment, ember-cli

I'm trying to deploy an ember-cli app to Azure Websites.
  When deploying to azure, you run a deployment script, which does the following:

```
 - npm install bower
 - npm install ember-cli
 - bower install
 - npm install
 - ember build
```

Well, it all seems to go well, until it hits the `ember build` step. I get an error:

```
this._handle.open(options.fd)

Error: EINVAL, Invalid argument
      at new Socket (net.js:156:18)
      at process.stdin (node.js:664:19)
      at ..... ember-cli\bin\ember:28:25
```

Searching around I found this link regardin the same problem with Grunt https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/pull/3608 
So, how would I disable stdin in Ember CLI? Any way I can do that, or any workaround so I can deploy the app?

I'm trying to make the build process on the webserver, and somehow this doesn't work on Azure. Does anyone have any experience with Azure?
  Thank you so much!

**UPDATE**

Please one of the two methods posted below by Felix Rieseberg or Justin Niessner.  Thank you to you both for the support and looking into this!

Comment: Are you running those installs + build on the server? If so, you can pre-build your app and just deploy the .html + .js files generated into the dist directory.

Comment: Yeah, I could to that. But it would have been really cool if I were able to built it on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm in the final steps of attempting this myself. I'm not sure how you set your deployment up, but I wanted mine to build the `dist` folder in the `%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%` folder and then only copy the resulting folder as part of the deploy.

I was struggling with the same issue that you're having until I saw the link that you included in your post. That gave me the crazy idea to use `grunt` and `grunt-shell` to call `ember build` instead of calling it directly from my deploy.cmd.

My Gruntfile.js is exceedingly simple:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
    shell: {
      build: {
        command: 'ember build -prod',
        options: {
          stdout: true,
          stdin: false
        }
      },
      test: {
        command: 'ember test',
        options: {
          stdout: true,
          stdin: false
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['shell:build'])
}
```

After that, I had a `dist` folder that could then be copied via the Kudu Sync command to `wwwroot`. If there's anything else you need to see, just let me know and I'll update my answer.

**Update**

I finally had a chance to clean things up and add some checks to make sure I'm not installing things that have already been installed. You can view my whole deploy.sh file at:

https://github.com/CrshOverride/EmberTodo/blob/master/deploy.sh

Comment: Hey, that's awesome, really cool. Unfortunately I cannot test this right now, I've moved away to building locally and deploying via FTP.  So it works for you right? If yes, I'm gonna mark the answer and I'm sure others will find the solution helpful, me included.

Comment: @tehmaestro - Building and deploying definitely works. Still struggling to get testing working though.

Answer (score 6):

I actually also figured out a way - and since I'm an Open Source guy at Microsoft, I just built a small npm module that takes care of everything. If you want a long explanation, [check this out](http://www.felixrieseberg.com/deploying-ember-cli-to-azure-websites/) - if you just want the tl;dr version:

`$ npm install ember-cli-azure-deploy --save-dev -g
$ azure-deploy init`

Comment: @Felix could You please write more extensive 'how to' about using Your _ember-cli-azure-deploy_ module? I am lost right after reading your blog. This http://www.ember-cli.com/#azure also is not enough for me to deploy Ember App to Azure. Best regards

Comment: I seem to see problems adding symlinks using your npm package Felix, there are a couple of issues detailing it in your github repo - https://github.com/felixrieseberg/ember-cli-azure-deploy/issues/18